# How to put method in map?

Tags: java, dictionary, functional-programming, first-class-functions

I have Strings where I need to find brackets `()`, `{}`, `[]` and using stack to check correctness and if there is a mistake to print the position of mistake . So i split them into char array and then want to check symbol by symbol and if its match my map execute my method of pushing/popping to/from the stack.

I imagine it like this:

```
ParentStack s = new ParentStack();
Map<Character, Method> map = new HashMap<Character, Method>();
map.put('(', s.push('('));
map.put(')', s.pop()); //then check if its opposite
```

So is there something like this? Or I have to use switches?

Comment: Check this blog post for checking correctness.. expand it to print position of mistake.. http://c-madeeasy.blogspot.com/2011/08/java-program-to-check-whether.html

Comment: Your "example" isn't even putting methods into the map. You are putting the return values of push and pop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the method instead of putting it into the map. What you could do instead is to put an instance of the `Runnable` interface into the map. `Runnable` is Javas default interface for any method that has no parameter list and no return value. If you need parameters or a return value, you might want to have a look at the interfaces in the package [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). For example `Supplier<T>` has a return value and `Consumer<T>` has one parameter.

Here is an example using Java 8 lambda expressions:

```
ParentStack s = new ParentStack();
Map<Character, Runnable> map = new HashMap<Character, Runnable>();
map.put('(', () -> s.push('('));
map.put(')', () -> s.pop());
```

And the usage:

```
map.get('(').run();
```

The `run()` method is declared by the `Runnable` interface and will call the method that you put into the map. Don't be confused by the different names.

Answer (score 1):

Since java is not a functional programming language (where functions are so-called [first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen)), you can't pass a function by reference. What you could do instead is create an interface with one method called for example `execute()`. you then implement this interface for each function you want to have and put these in the map, where you can call them easily and execute these "functions".

```
public interface function{
    void execute();
}
```

And (in java 8) your code could look something like this:

```
ParentStack s = new ParentStack();
Map<Character, Method> map = new HashMap<Character, Method>();
map.put('(', (Function) () -> s.push('('));
map.put(')', (Function) () -> s.pop());
```

Some people would even write it like that:

```
map.put('(', () -> s.push('('));
```

Which I don't think is as easy to read, but that's a matter of preference.

To execute your `Function` use:

```
map.get('(').execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BooleanSupplier` instead of `Method`.

```
    Stack<Character> s = new Stack<>();
    Map<Character, BooleanSupplier> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put('(', () -> { s.push('('); return true; });
    map.put(')', () -> !s.isEmpty() && s.pop() == '(');
```

And check like this.

```
    String str = "((ab)c)";
    int errorAt = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (map.containsKey(c))
            if (!map.get(c).getAsBoolean()) {
                errorAt = i;
                break;
            }
    }
    if (errorAt == -1 && s.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("OK!");
    else if (errorAt == -1)
        System.out.println("error at " + str.length());  // too few ')'
    else
        System.out.println("error at " + errorAt);  // too many ')'
```

Or you can use Stream API.

```
    int errorAt = IntStream.range(0, str.length())
        .filter(i -> map.containsKey(str.charAt(i)))
        .reduce(-1, (p, i) -> p >= 0 || map.get(str.charAt(i)).getAsBoolean() ? p : i);
```